# Magento security patch reinstall

Tags: security, magento, ssh, patch

I have just restored all my files for magento and I am trying to install the all the patches but i am getting this error can anyone help.

sh PATCH_SUPEE-5994.sh

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
checking file downloader/Maged/View.php
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
checking file downloader/template/messages.phtml
checking file get.php
checking file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
The next patch would create the file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285.sh

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
checking file app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/controllers/AdminhtmlController.php
checking file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/AdminGws/Model/Controllers.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/AdminGws/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Banner/controllers/Adminhtml/Banner/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/controllers/Adminhtml/UrlrewriteController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Cms/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Hierarchy.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Cms/controllers/Adminhtml/Cms/Hierarchy/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Cms/controllers/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/RevisionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Cms/controllers/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/VersionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Cms/controllers/Adminhtml/Cms/PageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/ImportExport/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/ImportExport/Model/Scheduled/Operation.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Logging/controllers/Adminhtml/LoggingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/PromotionPermissions/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/SearchController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/controllers/Adminhtml/Search/System/Config/TestconnectionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
The next patch would create the file downloader/Maged/.htaccess,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
The next patch would create the file downloader/lib/.htaccess,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
checking file downloader/template/settings.phtml
checking file errors/processor.php
```

sh PATCH_SUPEE-6482.sh

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Processor.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftregistry/search/form.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/giftregistry/search/form.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

sh PATCH_SUPEE-6788.sh

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file .htaccess
checking file .htaccess.sample
checking file app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/Helper/Data.php
The next patch would create the file app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/controllers/Adminhtml/MerchandiserController.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/controllers/AdminhtmlController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 22.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftRegistry/Model/Resource/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Rma/Model/Resource/Item.php
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/merchandiser.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/cache/additional.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/category/open.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/config/button.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/init.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/new/category.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/new/category/button.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/new/page/html/top-buttons.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/new/search/form.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file cron.php
checking file dev/tests/functional/.htaccess
checking file errors/processor.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 463 with fuzz 2.
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
checking file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

I have checked if just in case its already installed by testing on www.magereport.com and doing a scan and it shows as "not installed"

Comment: For which patches does magereport say 'not installed'?
All of them?